# Use a t function inside of a I18nextProvider? Is it possible?

Tags: reactjs, i18next, react-i18next

Is there a way to use a `t` function inside of a `I18nextProvider`?

The translation works in a children components. I want to pass a translatable elements to a `SEO` component.

Now i get `Uncaught ReferenceError: t is not defined` error.

The example makes more clear what I want to achieve:

```
**index.js**

import SEO from './components/villages/neighborhoods/SEO';
import { I18nextProvider, withTranslation } from 'react-i18next';
import i18n from './i18n';
import {createBrowserHistory} from 'history';
const customHistory = createBrowserHistory();

class App extends React.Component {
  
  render() {       

    var lang = i18n.language;    

    return (      
      <I18nextProvider i18n={i18n}>
        <div>               
          <SEO
            schema={t("Product")}
            title={t("metatile")}
            lang={i18n.language}
            path={`/${lang}`}
          />   
          <Router history={customHistory}>
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path={`/:lng(en|lt)?`} component={LandingPage} />
              <Route path={`/:lng(en|lt)?/test`} component={LandingPage}/>
              <Route component={NoMatch} />
            </Switch>
          </Router>
          <ModalContainer />
        </div>
      </I18nextProvider>
    )
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Is there a simple way to pass translatable `title` and `schema` variables without overwriting whole `index.js` code?

**updated SEO.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { Helmet } from 'react-helmet';

import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';
const { t } = useTranslation();

const SEO = ({
  schema, lang, title, description, keywords, base, path, contentType
}) => (
    <Helmet
      htmlAttributes={{
        lang: lang,
        itemscope: undefined,
        itemtype: `http://schema.org/${schema}`,
      }}
      title={t("title")}
      link={[
        { rel: 'canonical', href: base + path },
      ]}
      meta={[
        { name: 'description', content: description },
        { name: 'og:title', content: `${title}` },
        { name: 'og:type', content: contentType },
        { name: 'og:description', content: description },
      ]}
    />

  );
  

SEO.propTypes = {
  schema: PropTypes.string,
  lang: PropTypes.string,
  title: PropTypes.string,
  description: PropTypes.string,
  keywords: PropTypes.string,
  path: PropTypes.string,
  contentType: PropTypes.string,
};


export default SEO;
```

Comment: One thing you can do is send in the keys as props and then call `t(...)` inside `SEO`.

Comment: @usafder, you mean to use a `t` function inside of a `SEO` component? Like `const { t } = this.props;`? How do you suggest to send the `keys`? Example would be appreciated

Comment: Added the example in my answer.

Comment: Thank you! Of course it's my fault, the `SEO.js` was written with a little bit another approach. I haven't thought about it before posting question. So I'm trying to translate `title`, but getting this error: `Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:`. Any chance, how it could be fixed? I've updated my question with `SEO.js` code

Comment: Hooks can only be used within the component. Shift your `const { t } = useTranslation();` statement inside the `SEO` component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `App` component you can change the `schema` and `title` props for `SEO` as:

```
<SEO
  schema="Product"
  title="metatile"
  lang={lang}
  path={`/${lang}`}
/>
```

And then inside your `SEO` component you can use `t` either by using the `useTranslation` hook or by using the `withTranslation` HOC (both are provided by `react-i18next`):

#### By using useTranslation Hook:

```
import React from 'react';
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';

function SEO(props) {
  const { t } = useTranslation();

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{t(props.title)}</h1>
      <p>{t(props.schema)}</p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default SEO;
```

#### By using withTranslation HOC:

```
import React from 'react';
import { withTranslation } from 'react-i18next';

function SEO(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{props.t(props.title)}</h1>
      <p>{props.t(props.schema)}</p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default withTranslation()(SEO);
```